# Crystal reports if/else syntax

Tags: crystal-reports, formulas

The formula editor indicates this is wrong. How can I correct it?

```
If {upempl.status} = 'active' then 1 else 0
```

Comment: Try using  " not '

Comment: Where are you putting this logic? Into a standalone Formula object, or are you using it to, say, suppress a different field?

Comment: Also @CoSpringsGuy - Both single and double quotes are valid in Crystal Reports syntax. So long as you use the same kind on each end. (Source: IBM)

Comment: @4444 agreed.. I had the misplaced intent of ruling out ` vs ' because I was too busy at the moment to just explain that. Thanks for pointing that out though. I don't imagine there will be any more activity on this post anyway.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities as to why this is would be invalid:

- `{upempl.status}` isn't a String type, and therefore can't be compared to a string
- The formula needs to return a Boolean value, rather than `1` or `0`. In which case, replace your formula with the snippet below, which will return `true` and `false` instead:

---

```
 {upempl.status} = "active"
```